# Adding value from select query using DBquery in Yii2

Tags: yii2

i want to add value(string) in my select query..iam using dbquery..do anyone know how to do this?

```
    $tableA = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select("sm_wp.no_agenda,mfwp.nama_wp,sm_wp.jenis_surat, 
              sm_wp.nomor_surat, sm_wp.tgl_surat,sm_wp.perihal")
    ->from('sm_wp')
    ->leftjoin('mfwp', 'sm_wp.id_mfwp = mfwp.id')
    ;
```

from that query i got this table in my gridview

```
no_agenda nama_wp jenis_surat  nomor_surat  tgl_surat  perihal
---------  ------ -----------  -----------  ---------  -------
     1       xx       1            22       21/10/2019  bla
```

i want that table become like this

```
    no_agenda kategori  nama_wp jenis_surat  nomor_surat  tgl_surat  perihal
    ---------  ------  -----------  -----------  ---------  -------  -------
         1       foo        xx       1            22       21/10/2019  bla                          
         2       foo        yy       1            22       21/10/2019  ble
```

i want to add kategori in my gridview with same value (foo)..thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quoting by using [`\yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression)

```
$tableA = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(
        [
            new Expression(
                'sm_wp.no_agenda,mfwp.nama_wp,sm_wp.jenis_surat,
                sm_wp.nomor_surat, sm_wp.tgl_surat,sm_wp.perihal,
                "foo" as kategori'
            ),
        ]
    )
    ->from('sm_wp')
    ->leftjoin('mfwp', 'sm_wp.id_mfwp = mfwp.id')
```

Comment: before i tried it, iam sure thats the right answer..i found this article too,using new expression, but dont know how to write it correctly...thx mr aslam..